# How to install pgAdmin 4 using Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, pgadmin-4

I am trying to install `pgadmin4` using `Docker` in `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, but each time I create a container it crashes. Am I missing something in the below command

```
$ docker pull dpage/pgadmin4

$ docker run -p 80:80 \
    -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=atinesh.s@gmail.com' \
    -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin' \
    -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Comment: what are the errors you got ?

Comment: @LinPy Container gets created successfully without any error then it gets stopped

Comment: what did you get by trying `docker ps -a`

Comment: I think if you browse to `localhost:80` you will see the website

Comment: @LinPy `docker ps -a` output https://i.postimg.cc/G27VrffD/Screenshot-from-2019-10-24-16-46-23.png

Comment: what says `docker logs jovial_khorana` ?

Comment: `docker logs jovial_khorana` Outputs `You need to specify PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL and PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD environment variables`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue with following command

```
$ docker run -p 80:80 \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL="atinesh.s@gmail.com" \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD="admin" \
    -d dpage/pgadmin4
```